# Get nth-child in jquery javascript

Tags: jquery

i want to get nth-child an object for example

```
<div>
<img src="1.jpg" />
<img src="2.jpg" />
<img src="3.jpg" />
</div>
```

in jquery.

```
function func(i){
$("div img:nth-child(i)).css("display","none");
}
```

but i in double quotation Does not work.
I want to know another way.

Answer (score 2):

Just concatenate the variable in

```
function func(i){
    $("div img:nth-child(" + i + ")").css("display","none");
}
```

Or using template litterals
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```
function func(i){
    $(`div img:nth-child(${i})`).css("display","none");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the dynamic `nth-child` you can generate the selector with dynamically added value.

Check the working code:

```js
function func(i) {
  $("div img:nth-child(" + i + ")").css("display", "none");
}

func(2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img src="1.jpg" />
  <img src="2.jpg" />
  <img src="3.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the double quotations, your syntax is wrong. Try: 
$("div img:nth-child(" + i + ")").css("display","none");